# Redirection issue with traefik, haproxy and chrome from a subdomain to another not managed by traefik

Tags: apache, google-chrome, redirect, haproxy, traefik

I don't know if my title is very explicit but I made a diagram of our stack to explain my situation :

[image: infrastructure schema]

I am currently working on migrating a platform to a Docker environment (mysite.subdomain.com on the diagram).

My problem is the following: when I click on a link or redirect from mysite.subdomain.com to othersite.subdomain.com or anothersite.subdomain.com, I get the following error from traefik:

[image: 404 error from traefik]

If we try to access othersite.subdomain.com or anothersite.subdomain.com directly without first going through mysite.subdomain.com, it works.

If we try to access the URL from mysite.subdomain.com to othersite.subdomain.com with Curl or Internet Explorer it also works (the redirection works).

If we try to access an URL on internet like google.com for example, it works from any browser.

What i don't understand :

We click on a classic HTML link (a href=""), the URL in the browser changes well but the routing does not seem to behave in the classic way as if we were entering the URL by hand in the browser.

Our question is: Is there some kind of "network cache" on recent browsers that make sure that the navigation does not start "from scratch" when you are in the same domain?

If so, how can this be prevented? Is there a setting to be made in traefik? Haproxy? A setting to be made on Apache ?

Thank you in advance !

**EDIT 05/04/2022**

By clicking on the link with internet explorer we have two tcp sockets which open and the download works.
On the other hand with chrome and firefox, only one tcp socket opens and we get a 404 from traefik. which makes us think that all trafik passes through the same socket.

Comment: Have you tried redirecting with 302 code rather than 301? Browsers cache 301 redirects because it's permanent, but not 302.

Comment: By the way, if you want to be sure that's it's a problem with browsers caching redirections, you can set the URL to have a query parameter. I think those redirections are not cached.

Comment: @JérémyHalin We already tried to redirect with 301 or 302 and we had no difference, one of URLs we tried in direct link is generate dynamically for each spaces in our website. I also edit my question by adding that external links like google.com don't have any problem